# Django: a maximum value from a sum of two columns

Tags: django, django-models

I need a maximum value from a sum of two columns and if there are a few rows with the same price I want the one with the most recent date.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.


class Flight(models.Model):
    outboundPrice = models.FloatField()
    returnPrice = models.FloatField()
    timeCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I'm currently using this query:

```
>>> Flight.objects.values('timeCreated').annotate(max=Max(F('outboundPrice') + F('returnPrice'))).order_by('-max')[0]
{'timeCreated': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 16, 13, 0, 12, 525111, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'max': 205}
```

which translates two the following MySQL query:

```
mysql [lab]> SELECT timeCreated, MAX((outboundPrice + returnPrice)) AS max FROM flights_flight GROUP BY timeCreated ORDER BY timeCreated ASC LIMIT 1;
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| timeCreated                | max                |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| 2018-06-16 13:00:12.525111 | 205.98000000000002 |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but that's not the most recent one:

```
mysql [wizzair]> SELECT timeCreated, MAX((outboundBasePrice + returnBasePrice)) AS max FROM flights_result GROUP BY timeCreated ORDER BY timeCreated ASC;
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| timeCreated                | max                |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| 2018-06-16 13:00:12.525111 | 205.98000000000002 |
| 2018-06-16 14:00:13.404816 | 205.98000000000002 |
| 2018-06-16 15:00:12.927219 | 205.98000000000002 |
| 2018-06-16 16:00:12.595076 | 205.98000000000002 |
| 2018-06-16 17:00:11.226041 | 205.98000000000002 |
| 2018-06-16 18:00:12.692635 | 205.98000000000002 |
| 2018-06-16 19:47:51.000000 | 201.98000000000002 |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Basically I want to query on which date the ticket in both ways was most expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **add an extra ordering criterium**:

```
Flight.objects.values('timeCreated').annotate(
    max=Max(F('outboundPrice') + F('returnPrice'))
).order_by('-max', '-timeCreated').first()
```

So here in case of a *tie*, we also sort in descending order on `timereated`, such that the most recent is picked.

In case you want the first entry, you can use `.first()`, which is more self-explaining. In case there is no such row, it will return `None` instead.